# Определение статуса ссылки облака

Tags: python, requests, права-доступа, dropbox, яндекс-диск

у меня есть очень много ссылок на Mega/Yandex disc/Dropbox папки, проблема в том что множества из них заблокированы, и мне нужно как то узнать заблокирована ссылка или нет

Сразу скажу, что через

```
import requests
print(requests.get('url'))
```

Это сделать не получится, так как результат ответа будет `200`, потому что будет ответ от html страницы.

Comment: Ну вот и анализируйте эту самую html-страницу, наверное?

Comment: Так тоже не получится, так как даже если ссылка инвалид, то тебя выведет на html страницу, где идёт запрос на расшифровку ссылки

Comment: Вобщем, даже если ссылка заблокированна, тебе выдаст одну и туже html

Comment: "тебе выдаст одну и туже html" - чем не решение? то, что отличается - валидная, незаблокированная ссылка

Comment: ```import requests as r

s1= "https://mega.nz/folder/nAYjDSjB#1Y_Hzd9DI5Bn8QLwUNNz3A" #рабочая ссылка
s2= "https://mega.nz/folder/nAYjDSjB#1Y_H292jjwi292i28292829dnnxnxnx" #инвалид

if r.get(s1).text == r.get(s2).text: print(True)```